# How do I fix this moving problem in my 2d game in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm currently trying to learn how to make 2d games in unity. I bought a course in uedemy. Apparently it doesn't quite work well with the moving part. I created an animation cycle like this:

[image]

Apparently after some moving he gets stuck and don't make any animations at all (other then the idle animation).

[image]

I don't know the language very well so I don't know exactly what's going on in there. This is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class PlayerCtrl : MonoBehaviour
{


[Tooltip("this is a positive integer which speed up the player movement")]
public int speedBoost;  // set this to 5
public float jumpSpeed; // set this to 600

Rigidbody2D rb;
SpriteRenderer sr;
Animator anim;
bool isJumping;


void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update()
{
    float playerSpeed = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"); // value will be 1, -1 or 0
    playerSpeed *= speedBoost;

    if (playerSpeed != 0)
        MoveHorizontal(playerSpeed);
    else
        StopMoving();

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        Jump();

    ShowFalling();
}

void MoveHorizontal(float playerSpeed)
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(playerSpeed, rb.velocity.y);

    if (playerSpeed < 0)
        sr.flipX = true;
    else if (playerSpeed > 0)
        sr.flipX = false;

    if (!isJumping)
        anim.SetInteger("State", 1);
}

void StopMoving()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb.velocity.y);

    if (!isJumping)
        anim.SetInteger("State", 0);
}

void ShowFalling()
{
    if (rb.velocity.y < 0)
    {
        anim.SetInteger("State", 3);
    }
}

void Jump()
{
    isJumping = true;
    rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpSpeed)); // simply make the player jump in the y axis or upwards
    anim.SetInteger("State", 2);
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        isJumping = false;
}
}
```

Im Happy if someone could help me with this one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, unfortunately, I don't think there's enough info here to make a proper diagnosis of the issue. Additionally, your two screenshots are not helpful because they are the same exact screenshot and they are showing the jumping transition. So can't really get anything from that.

But some things you can try would be to [make sure that your animations are set to loop](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/Manual/LoopingAnimationClips.html). If they are not looping, they will only play once and won't continue. However, it sounds more like something is breaking in your movement script and not properly updating your animation states so you'll want to do some debugging there.

I would try using a `Debug.Log()` to make sure your State is being set correctly. For example, after each line where you use `anim.SetInteger` add `Debug.Log(anim.GetInteger("State"));`

Example:

```
void Jump()
{
    isJumping = true;
    rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpSpeed)); // simply make the player jump in the y axis or upwards
    anim.SetInteger("State", 2);
    
    // Debug - add this
    Debug.Log(anim.GetInteger("State"));
}
```

You can also add that line directly to the `Update()` method instead and it will constantly log to the unity console while playing. This way is just a little cleaner and less spamming in the console.

Another thing I'd recommend would be to pose this question to the actual Udemy course, asking the instructor for guidance. If the Udemy course is outdated, that might also have an effect and you'll want to make sure you're using a course that is up to date (although I doubt that is the case.)

If you can provide some more information, maybe we can help you out a bit more.